# Windows 10 Home for Company

Tags: windows-10

May I know is it legit to use `Windows 10 Home Edition` for a company?

The company is a small size company and it is a car park management company.

Confuse as I search on google but with conflict answers.

Comment: You can use whatever version is appropriate, you just won't get whatever featured there are in the higher versions such as the ability to connect to an active directory domain.

Comment: Software licensing questions are considered off-topic on Super User.

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using any "Home" edition of Windows within a professional work environment.  In my experience, you will eventually encounter some capability that you really need/want which would be there by default within a Professional or Enterprise edition.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking if something is legal. We are not lawyers.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security-winpc/can-we-use-windows-10-home-edition-for-business/2037e56c-2eee-4867-ae4a-c4c03b47c292?auth=1) answer, it's fine.

> You can use either version for whatever purposes you have.

Also, I believe the different names as "Home", "Pro" or "Enterprise" are only for marketing purposes, so you'd know what features are enabled and who are the main target group.

Answer (score 0):

That's legal but not reasonable and appropriate. Since BitLocker, Group Policy and join domain etc features are not available for Home Edition.

Here is a detailed Edition comparison:

**[Find out which Windows is right for you](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/windowsforbusiness/compare)**

Comment: might not need to join domains tho